# Beginner Digital Nomad-Visa for Canada

Tags: visa, immigration, canada, business, digital-nomads

I’m confused. I want to stay in Canada for 3 to 6 months to get my online business going take a break from America and get other skills that I would learn online while there and maybe take a language course on site. The visas that they offer seem like they’re a little bit too permanent and if it’s temporary it does not seem to cover work online. I’m not sure which one I would fall under.

Comment: I assume you want to take a break from the USA? Canada is also America.

Comment: What citizenship(s) do you have. Neither Canada nor the US really encourage what you seem to be describing. If you have a TN-eligible profession (like an engineering degree), there may be a possible way to claim that you are going to Canada to start a business (or a Canadian branch of a business you have in (I'm assuming) the US)

Comment: It’s an online business, basically work online my title would be digital nomad because I would claim the business or LLC before I go. All uses and products would be in the USA as I am a US citizen. I would operate the business remotely.